# Xcode will not load on any version

Tags: xcode

I am on a 2020 M1 Pro using on macOS Monterey 12.6, Xcode 14 (It was happening with Xcode 13.3 and 13.2 as well). Opening Xcode will takes hours to load a project (even a new project) and I am not sure how to fix this.

I've tried restarting Xcode, deleting derived data, downloading previous versions, nothing has helped.

Is this a hardware issue?

[image]

Comment: Did you delete the Xcode preferences?

Comment: @JeshuaLacock how would I do that? Unfortunately I'm unable to click 'Xcode' -> 'Preferences' in the top tool bar

Comment: Open your preferences folder in the Finder at ~/Library/Preferences/. Look for Xcode. I see a few including com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist. Trash them. You can open your preference folder by pasting this in a Terminal: 'open ~/Library/Preferences'

Comment: @JeshuaLacock fortunately Xcode loaded after about 13 hours, I will try this if it happens again

Comment: @tHatpart same thing happens to me. Have you fine any solution?

Comment: @solarenqu my solution: upgraded to a M1 Pro

Comment: @solarenqu I have a bad feeling it's a first generation M1 thing

Comment: I'm using M1 PRO.. But i solved this.. It happens to me if the project placed a directory that are syncronized to iCloud. Try please to remove the project from directory that are syncronized to iCloud.. :)

Comment: @solarenqu how do I do that

Comment: @tHatpart just move the project out from Documents directory. (If the Documents synced to iCloud)

Comment: @solarenqu I've tried removing it in finder via drag and drop, but nothing happens